# ngIf flag not updating the span element when value changes in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular8

I am displaying a flash message if the user had created a post successfully. I am emitting a value after creation of the post and capturing the value in ngOnInit of the redirected component to change the flag which i use to display the flash message.

I also have another flash message in the same component which will display after the user successfully logins and that is working fine.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.userSub=this.userService.loginStatusChanged.subscribe(
      (data:{loginFlag:boolean, userId:string, userName:string})=>{

        this.user = data.userName;
        if(data.loginFlag){

          if(this.previousRouteService.getPreviousUrl()=='/log-in'){
            this.loginFlashMessageFlag=true;
            setTimeout(()=>{
              this.loginFlashMessageFlag=false;
            },5000)
          }
        }

        this.kavithaiService.kavithaiStatusChanged.subscribe(
          (data:any)=>{
            console.log(data);
            this.createPostFlashMessageFlag = true;
            setTimeout(()=>{
              this.createPostFlashMessageFlag=false;
            },5000)

          }
        )

      }
    )
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="loginFlashMessage"  @flashMessageAnimation *ngIf="loginFlashMessageFlag">வணக்கம், {{user}} !</span>

<span id="createPostFlashMessage"  @flashMessageAnimation *ngIf="createPostFlashMessageFlag" >Flash Message</span>
```

The console.log(data) inside the kavithai service subscription is displaying correctly, but the dom is not changing. The Login flash message is displaying properly after login though.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What is this syntax? `@flashMessageAnimation` ? a directive? If so, can we see the code?

Comment: This is an angular animation.

Comment: correct. That is angular animation. ```@flashMessageAnimation``` is the animation trigger which resides inside ```@component``` decorator.

Comment: what is the changeDetection in your component ?  ``@Component({ changeDetection :value  })``

Comment: @AbolfazlR - I don't have any value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add change detection.

Add

```
private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef
```

in constructor.

Add

```
this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
```

after you update the flags.

Comment: Where should ```this.changeDetect.detectChanges();``` be added ? I tried adding it after ```this.createPostFlashMessageFlag = true;``` it gives me an error message ```ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view```

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked(){ this.changeDetect.detectChanges();}